# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError in hibernate configuration file

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am working on writing a most minimal program to do CRUD operations on mysql using hibernate in Java.

I am following below tutorial at:

https://medium.com/@amrut.patil88/crud-with-java-hibernate-and-mysql-part-1-f6b1d6f7dbbf

I have created user in mysql and started it.

CreateStudentDemo.java is :

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

//import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create a Session Factory

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().
                configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
                addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).
                buildSessionFactory();


        //create a Session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        try{

            System.out.println("Creating a new Student object...");

            //create the Student object
            Student student = new Student("Paul", "Walker","paul.walker@gmail.com");

            //start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            //Save the Student object to the database
            session.save(student);

            System.out.println("Java object saved to the database");
            //commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        }finally{

            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Student.java is:

```
//package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name=”student”)
public class Student {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name=”id”)
 private int id;

 @Column(name=”first_name”)
 private String firstName;

 @Column(name=”last_name”)
 private String lastName;

 @Column(name=”email”)
 private String email;
 public Student(){

 }

 public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 this.lastName = lastName;
 this.email = email;
 }
public int getId() {
 return id;
 }
public void setId(int id) {
 this.id = id;
 }
public String getFirstName() {
 return firstName;
 }
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 }
public String getLastName() {
 return lastName;
 }
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
 this.lastName = lastName;
 }
public String getEmail() {
 return email;
 }
public void setEmail(String email) {
 this.email = email;
 }
@Override
 public String toString() {
 return “Student [id=” + id + “, firstName=” + firstName + “, lastName=” + lastName + “, email=” + email + “]”;
 }
}
```

**In Student.java,**

my eclipse is showing error on :  `@Table(name=”student”)`

> ```
> "syntax error on tokens. delete these tokens".
> ```

Is it because some library/jar is not installed?

hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath:hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory> <! — allows us to get session objects for connecting to the database -->
<! — JDBC Database connection settings -->
 <property name=”connection.driver_class”>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name=”connection.url”>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false</property>
 <property name=”connection.username”>hb_student2</property>
 <property name=”connection.password”>Student123&$,</property>
<! — JDBC connection pool settings … using built-in test pool -->
 <property name=”connection.pool_size”>1</property>
<! — Select our SQL dialect -->
 <property name=”dialect”>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<! — Echo the SQL to stdout -->
 <property name=”show_sql”>true</property>
<! — Set the current session context -->
 <property name=”current_session_context_class”>thread</property>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have created a project in eclipse and have copied "required" jars from hibernate downnload.

Now, when I run CreateStudentDemo.java, I get below error:

```
Jun 02, 2020 2:57:29 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.17.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:14)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,21]
Message: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:485)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:463)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:126)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,21]
Message: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.EventReaderDelegate.peek(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor$NamespaceAddingEventReader.peek(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleCharacters(StAXEventConnector.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(StAXEventConnector.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:460)
    ... 7 more
```

Please help.

Comment: Other than what @Bashir already pointed out, the problem was with the mysql password in the hibernate config file. It contained special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are using a special character `”` instead of `"`. there is big difference between them. so try to replace `”` with `"` in all your code. this happens always especially if you copy code from a tutorial which is using wrong characters.

also in the XML file, for the comment it must be done this way `<!-- comment -->` and not `<! — comment -->`

copy paste, I replaced all of them for you :)

**Student.java** :

```
//package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="id")
 private int id;

 @Column(name="first_name")
 private String firstName;

 @Column(name="last_name")
 private String lastName;

 @Column(name="email")
 private String email;
 public Student(){

 }

 public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 this.lastName = lastName;
 this.email = email;
 }
public int getId() {
 return id;
 }
public void setId(int id) {
 this.id = id;
 }
public String getFirstName() {
 return firstName;
 }
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 }
public String getLastName() {
 return lastName;
 }
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
 this.lastName = lastName;
 }
public String getEmail() {
 return email;
 }
public void setEmail(String email) {
 this.email = email;
 }
@Override
 public String toString() {
 return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
 }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml** :

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "classpath:hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- allows us to get session objects for connecting to the database -->
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hb_student2</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Student123&$,</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings … using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Bashir, thanks for making it so easy for me. The error in Student.java is gone, but ueven now when I run CreateStudentDemo.java, I am getting the same error...

Comment: the error now is on which line exactly? and do you have other classes or files that you copied from the tutorial? make sure you changed **hibernate.cfg.xml** because the comment tag was wrong, I edited the answer so I don't know if you copied it before or after my edit

Comment: refresh the page, and if there is an error, please tell me in which line and what is the error. But I think it will work fine.. I hope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215161/discussion-between-biologic-and-bashir).